# How to convert np array back to binary with specific dtype?

Tags: numpy, binary, type-conversion

I managed to read a binary file with

```
dt = np.dtype([('ID','i4'), ('OriType',('S1')), 'DesType',('S1')), ('VOT','f4')])
records = np.fromfile('mybinary.bin', dt)
```

How can I write it back? I tried to use `np.tofile()`, but it says it can't convert in binary mode and also the input is `format='%s'` and I don't know how to use it example. Could you give the exact code for writing it back?

Comment: *"... it says it can't convert in binary mode ..."*  Please show the exact code that you ran, and the exact error message that you got.  The best would be a complete, self-contained example that we can simply copy and run (i.e. inlcude all the import statements and code to generate sample data).  See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for more details.

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding. But that's the exactly the two lines that I used. There's is binary file in the default workspace called 'mybinary.bin'. And the code simply loads it with np.fromfile(), with the dt defined in the first line. I'm just curious if there's similar way to save it back. i.e., save the numpy array 'records' back to binary file with these specified data type for each column. Thank you!

Comment: You didn't show the line that generates the error.  You wrote "I tried to use np.tofile(), but it says it can't convert ...".  Show the exact call to `tofile()` that you used, and show the full error message (copy and paste it into the question).

Comment: I didn't even start using tofile() method, because I don't know how to write the 'fortmat' part so that the first 4 bytes are for the 'ID', the 5th byte is for the "OriType", the sixth byte is for the 'DesType', and so on.